# Entity Framework 6.2.0 - DbContext that automatically saves which user created or updated a DbSet value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

As the title says we need to store which user updated or created a specific value. Previously we only needed to save `CreatedDate` and `UpdatedDate`. This was quite easy, we had all our entities inherit from an abstract base class 
 called `EntityBase` which implemented the interface `IEntity` that had these values. `DbContext` `SaveChanges` was then overriden and if a specific entity implemented `IEntity` the values were set based on `EntityState.Added` or `EntityState.Modified`.

```
interface IEntity
{
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

}

public abstract class EntityBase<T1>: IEntity
{
    public T1 Id { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

However a new requirement is that we also need to save which user has made the changes. A simple solution would be to add the user via the constructor and not have an empty constructor. However this proves a problem when using migrations among others:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<CatalogServiceContext, Configuration>());
var migrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
```

> The target context 'CatalogService.Data.Context.CatalogServiceContext'
>   is not constructible. Add a default constructor or provide an
>   implementation of IDbContextFactory.

```
public class CatalogServiceContext : DbContext
{

    private readonly string _currentUser;

    public CatalogServiceContext(string currentUser) : base("name=CatalogContext")
    {
        _currentUser = currentUser;
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;

        foreach (var changedEntity in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            if (changedEntity.Entity is IEntity entity)
            {
                switch (changedEntity.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        entity.CreatedDate = now;
                        entity.CreatedBy = _currentUser;
                        entity.UpdatedDate = now;
                        entity.UpdatedBy = _currentUser;
                        break;

                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedDate).IsModified = false;
                        Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
                        entity.UpdatedDate = now;
                        entity.UpdatedBy = _currentUser;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I tried implementing a `IDbContextFactory` but it has a similar problem.

> The context factory type
>   'CatalogService.Data.Context.CatalogServiceContextFactory' does not
>   have a public parameterless constructor. Either add a public
>   parameterless constructor, create an IDbContextFactory implementation
>   in the context assembly, or register a context factory using
>   DbConfiguration.

```
public class CatalogServiceContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<CatalogServiceContext>
{
    private readonly string _currentUser;

    public CatalogServiceContextFactory(string currentUser)
    {
        _currentUser = currentUser;
    }

    public CatalogServiceContext Create()
    {
        return new CatalogServiceContext(_currentUser);
    }
}
```

A workaround is two methods in `EntityBase` that needs to be called each time a value is updated or created. This works but the best solution is still a forced user in the constructor in my opinion. Is there anyone else with a similar demand that have solved it? I would like to solve it in the `DbContext` and not use a repository abstraction for each `DbSet`.

```
public virtual EntityBase<T1> SetCreateFields(string currentUser)
{
    CreatedBy = currentUser;
    UpdatedBy = currentUser;
    return this;
}

public virtual EntityBase<T1> SetUpdateFields(string currentUser)
{
    UpdatedBy = currentUser;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: *A simple solution would be to add the user via the constructor and not have an empty constructor* Why insist on constructor injection? What drawbacks are from injecting this using a property or a method? Whoever calls your dbcontext constructor that has this one extra parameter, could also call a parameterless one and just inject the user data in any other way.

Comment: @WiktorZychla The benefit, as I see it, is that the property will be set whenever the Context is created (`new`). It is easy to forget to call a specific method or set a property imao. If I can have a compiler warning about a value that I'm expecting I like to have it.

Comment: You could always put the `Obsolete` over the parameterless constructor.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Absolutely but it feels a bit "hacky"

Comment: Yes, it is. It only aims to follow your direction. I approach this in a completely different way. There's no plugging the user name into the context, rather, there's a separate *username factory* with injectable providers. The overridden `SaveChanges` has a direct dependency to the factory but implementation details cah vary (as they depend on injectable providers). This way there's still a parametersless constructor and the `SaveChanges` just asks for the username. I am not proposing this alternative approach as an answer, though, as you seem to be very focused on your particular approach.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I'm always open to suggestions, my approach was simply my initial thought given that it worked with `CreatedDate` and `UpdatedDate ` before.

Comment: It worked only because this information can be obtained through the dependency to a concrete class (which is not injectable then). Now do the same with your user name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to solve it like this:

```
public class CatalogServiceContext : DbContext
{
    public ICurrentUser CurrentUser;

    [Obsolete("Use CatalogServiceContextUserWrapper instead")]
    public CatalogServiceContext() : base("name=CatalogContext")
    {

    }

    ...


public class CatalogServiceContextUserWrapper
{
    public CatalogServiceContext Context;

    public CatalogServiceContextUserWrapper(CatalogServiceContext context, ICurrentUser currentUser)
    {
        context.CurrentUser = currentUser;
        this.Context = context;
    }
}
```